# can not login my website with selenium phantomjs webdriver

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

Following is my code used to test login into my site, however, it does't work. The snapshot indicates it hangs in login button with status "logging in...". Does anyone encounter this before? Any suggestion? Thanks!

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from selenium import webdriver
import time

from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
dcap = dict(DesiredCapabilities.PHANTOMJS)
dcap["phantomjs.page.settings.resourceTimeout"] = ("10000")
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(desired_capabilities=dcap)
#driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.set_window_size(1280, 800)
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.get("http://<mysite login url>")

content = driver.save_screenshot('login.jpg')

user_name=driver.find_element_by_id('TANGRAM__PSP_4__userName')
user_name_text = user_name.text
print(user_name_text)
user_name.clear()
user_name.send_keys("<username>")

password=driver.find_element_by_id('TANGRAM__PSP_4__password')
password.clear()
password.send_keys('<passowrd>')
#driver.current_window_handle
driver.save_screenshot('aftersendkeys.jpg')

submit_button=driver.find_element_by_id('TANGRAM__PSP_4__submit')
submit_button.submit()
#submit_button.submit()
driver.save_screenshot('aftersubmit.jpg')

#time.sleep(10)
#driver.implicitly_wait(5)
#driver.implicitly_wait(3000)
#driver.set_script_timeout(3000)
#submit_button.submit()
driver.save_screenshot('after1000ms.jpg')
cookie= driver.get_cookies()
response = driver.current_url

print cookie
print(response)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should wait some seconds after you pushed the submit button as the webpage will take some time to process your request.

```
submit_button=driver.find_element_by_id('TANGRAM__PSP_4__submit')
submit_button.submit()

time.sleep(10) // time may have to be adapted to your webpage speed

driver.save_screenshot('aftersubmit.jpg')
```

Comment: after setting time.sleep(15), I found the webpage notice me login timeout. I think it should be the issue of our website. It may not support phantomjs.